# Conway's cosmological theorem on look-and-say sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

The most famous look-and-say sequence is
$$1,11,21,1211,111221,\ldots$$
where the next term in the sequence corresponds to reading off the previous term, e.g. the term after $1211$ is one $1$, one $2$, two $1$, or $111221$.

I was reading the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence) on look-and-say sequences, in which it says in the section on [cosmological decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence#Cosmological_Decay):

> Conway's cosmological theorem: Every sequence eventually splits
>   ("decays") into a sequence of "atomic elements", which are finite
>   subsequences that never again interact with their neighbors. There are
>   92 elements containing the digits 1, 2, and 3 only, which John Conway
>   named after the natural chemical elements. There are also two
>   "transuranic" elements for each digit other than 1, 2, and 3.

What is this paragraph saying? I don't understand what it means by the sequences eventually splitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that for any sequence seed $a_0$, we eventually arrive at a point where $a_k$ can be written as the concatenation $b_0c_0$, such that all future $a_m, m > k$, can similarly be written as the concatenation $b_{m-k}c_{m-k}$; that is, the end of $b_i$ never mixes with the start of $c_i$, for $i \geq 0$.  (The above is not intended to limit the splits to one at a time; I don't know the exact dynamics.)

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! When they write that "There are $92$ elements containing the digits $1$, $2$, and $3$ only...", they mean that there are only $92$ atomic elements (containing only these $3$ digits), and that all sequences are eventually composed of elements from this finite set of atomic elements (and the transuranic ones)?

Comment: I'm guessing so, but I really don't know; I'm sort of curious myself about the transuranic elements.